# Spacing in captions

Tags: graphics, captions, subfloats, minipage, sidebyside

How do I remove this space in the captions and make it look like continuous text in subfigure (b)?
[image]

Here is my code,

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=35mm,height=33mm]{DPT_hardware_2_png}
\footnotesize{(a) $V_{GS}$(Ch1), $V_{DS}$(Ch3), $I_D$(Ch4), Scale: t = 50 $\mu$s/div, Ch1: 20 
              V/div, Ch3: 10 V/div, Ch4: 5 A/div}
\label{fig:x}
\end{minipage}
 %\centering
 \hspace{0.5cm}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=35mm,height=33mm]{DPT_hardware_corr}
  \footnotesize{(b)Simulated waveform:$V_{DS}, I_D, V_{GS}$ Blue: $V_D$, Red: $V_{GS}$, Black: 
      $I_D$}
  \label{fig:y}
  \end{minipage}
 \caption{\footnotesize{Plot of $V_{DS}$, $V_{GS}$, $I_D$;(a) Experimental \& (b) Simulated 
   results}}
\label{fig:sboost2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: note size commands do not take an argument so `\footnotesize{...}` should be `\footnotesize ...` but you should not have size commands in `\caption` (as well as being logically wrong, it will mess up the list of figures) just use `\caption` then specify captions should use `\footnotesize` and `\raggedright` (to remove the stretched spaces) formatting using the  `caption` package.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=35mm,height=33mm]` it is usually best to only specify one of `width` or `height`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you looking for something like this:

[image]

MWE (Minimal Working Example) which produce above image, instead of `minipage` use `subfigure` environment defined in the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf, justification=RaggedRight}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{$V_{GS}$ (Ch1), $V_{DS}$ (Ch3), $I_D$ (Ch4), Scale: $t = \qty{50}{\micro\second/div}$, 
          Ch1: \qty{20}{V/div}, Ch3: \qty{10}{V/div}, Ch4: \qty{5}{A/div}}
\label{fig:x}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Simulated waveform: $V_{DS}, I_D, V_{GS}$ Blue: $V_D$, Red: $V_{GS}$, Black:
      $I_D$}
\label{fig:y}
\end{subfigure}
 \caption{Plot of $V_{DS}$, $V_{GS}$, $I_D$; (a) Experimental, (b) Simulated
   results}
\label{fig:sboost2}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```